# Does Google Play library have backwards compatibility support? (And other libraries)

Tags: android

I was reading this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/ and I find it amazing that this one and many others never state what versions they support.

There must be a simple list which contains what libraries are for what api versions, not just Google Play library but for everything else, from reading file paths to camera api. An example would be just the camera api 2, which is for api version 21 and above. A nice list listing all of this would be very helpful!

It's extremely time consuming tracking down all of this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there is one - in [packages documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) you can easily filter by API number.

Comment: Oh: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html Doesn't state API versions directly :/

Answer (score 1):

Official Android APIs have their API number define on official Android documentation like @sebap123 said.

Google Play Services isn't part of Android itself. It's a complimentary add-on. Google Play Services runs on Android 2.3 or higher. All new GPS APIs included in GPS will run on all these devices that have GPS(Android 2.3 or higher). Unlike new Android APIs that only run on new version of Android.

Comment: So your saying that Google Play services *should* work on all versions of Android higher than 2.3?